# Listing only files in directory

Tags: java, file, directory

I have a folder with following structure

```
C:/rootDir/

rootDir has following files

test1.xml
test2.xml
test3.xml
testDirectory <------- This is a subdirectory inside rootDir
```

I'm only interested in the XML files inside rootDir because if I use JDOM to read the XML, the following code also considers the files inside `testDirectory` and spits out `content not allowed exception`

```
File testDirectory = new File("C://rootDir//");
File[] files = testDirectory.listFiles();
```

How can I exclude the subdirectory while using the `listFiles` method? Will the following code work?

```
File testDirectory = new File("C://rootDir//");
File[] files = testDirectory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml");
    }
});
```

Comment: *"Will the following code work?"*  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I couldn't try it now cuz my JDK has been uninstalled for some reasons and I don't have admin rights to install it. :( I know it's lame..

Comment: sorry about that @AndrewThompson . I'll keep that in mind.. ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) instead, as it will give you access to the actual file, then include a check for [`File#isFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29)

```
File testDirectory = new File("C://rootDir//");
File[] files = testDirectory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        String name = pathname.getName().toLowerCase();
        return name.endsWith(".xml") && pathname.isFile();
    }
});
```

Comment: Not bad of a piece of unchecked code :P

Comment: In case of network file system (NFS or Samba) pathname.isFile() will most probably create a remote request for every file.

Comment: @30thh Yes, and?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Every request costs time. The amount of request could be a limited (or even billed) resource. For example AWS Elastic File System has a hard limitation of 7000 requests per second.

Comment: @30thh What's alternative?

Comment: @MadProgrammer the alternative is to avoid this usecase ;-) One solution could be making assumption and catch exceptions instead of pre-validation.

Comment: @30thh Well, since the question relates to local file structure, I'm assuming it's not an issue as it relates to the question been asked

Answer (score 14):

Easier is to realise that the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object has an [isDirectory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) method, which would seem as if it were written to answer this very question:

```
File testDirectory = new File("C://rootDir//");
File[] files = testDirectory.listFiles();
for (File file : files) {
    if ( (file.isDirectory() == false) && (file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".xml") ) {
       // do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File testDirectory = new File("C://rootDir//");
File[] files = testDirectory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
 {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml");
    }});
```

What is the problem with above code. You can use this for listing files by excluding subfolders.

FileFilter also do's same thing but it will be used when file name is not sufficent to listing the files. i.e if you want list all hidden files or readonly file etc. you can use FilteFilter