# list all files in folder excluding subdirectories

Tags: java, list

I use a specific file to load to my application. The user provides the path and I need to get the correct file. If the file isn't there I want to notify the user. I need to scan the folder the user provides. I **don't want to check sub-directories**. I use the following:

```
File f = new File(fileName);
        String[] allFiles = f.list();
        for (String files:allFiles) {
```

I don't want the f.list() to go recursively into all the sub-directories as there might be many files there and is a waste of time for me as if the file is not in the top directory then I can't do something anyway.

I couldn't find anything on google/stack overflow - can anyone suggest a solution to save on this time?

thanks,

Comment: Take a look to this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391367/listing-only-files-in-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391367/listing-only-files-in-directory)

Comment: But `File.list()` does not "go recursively into all the sub-directories".